# Why are double parentheses in tuples converted to single parentheses (Python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I declare `a` as `((5, 3))`, I want `a[0]` to be equal to `(5, 3)`. However, Python simpifies the expression to `(5, 3)`.

Why are tuples simplified like that and do I have to use lists to express the same thing? `((5, 3), (3, 8))` works just fine.

Comment: ``(...)`` is not a tuple. ``(...,)`` is a tuple, as is ``(..., ...)`` and such. Compare to ``(1 + 3) * 4``.

Comment: One-item tuples must end with a comma:  `((5, 3), )`

Comment: @komatiraju032 Kind of, the answer I was looking for was already in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tuples with a single element must be declared with the syntax `(x,)`. Otherwise, parentheses are interpreted as a means of clarifying computations (or changing priorities with respect to operations).

Answer (score 2):

You can add a blank value as a second item, so that Python doesn't simplify the tuple:

```
# Python Terminal
>>> ((5, 3))
(5, 3)
>>> ((5, 3),)
((5, 3),)
>>> ((5, 3),)[0]
(5, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you declare `a=((1, 2), )` this will give you a tuple where the first element is another tuple.

```
a = ((1,2), )
print(a[0])
# Output: (1, 2)
```